# CSV generate data format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

I'm using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv` library to export some data by generating a `csv` file. The above mentioned library supports the following data format

```
const csvData = [
  ["firstname", "lastname", "email"],
  ["Ahmed", "Tomi", "ah@smthing.co.com"],
  ["Raed", "Labes", "rl@smthing.co.com"],
  ["Yezzi", "Min l3b", "ymin@cocococo.com"]
];
```

The data i want to export is getting from a API response. I'm mapping my data array to create a data structure as above.

```
    const csvData = [
      ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],
      transaction.transactionData && transaction.transactionData.map((item, key) => {
           return (
               [item.A, item.B, item.C, item.D, item.E, item.F, item.G, item.H]
           )
      })
     ]
```

But this won't output the structure i want (the one i showed you in the beginning). How can i map my data so it takes the required structure.

i console logged `csvData` and it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code return another result like this:

```
[["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"],[[...],[...]]]
```

this code is work correctly :

```
const output = []
output.push(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"])
transaction.transactionData && transaction.transactionData.forEach(item => {
           output.push (
               [item.A, item.B, item.C, item.D, item.E, item.F, item.G, item.H]
           )
      })
```

We must define a variable as an array for our structure. after that push our rows in our variable.